# Android Jetpack navigation: One activity with several navigation views

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am considering the new [android jetpack navigation best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9O1D_Ytk0xg) where there should only be one activity in each application. I want to use one activity to implement the following menus in fragments, but I'm very insecure about what the best practices are when implementing several menus in the same application.

**`BottomNavigationView` ([Reference repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)):**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:
[image: BttomNavigationView]

**DrawerLayout ([Reference repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower)):**

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/garden_nav_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_garden"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Considering these examples from google there are no clear answers as of how to implement both views in one activity using best practices, because each example only uses one form of navigation view for their app, respectively `DrawerLayout`, or `BottomNavigationView`.

The questions are:
1. What are the best practices for making activity with different navigation views for different fragments? For example, several fragments using `DrawerLayout`, and other fragments using `BottomNavigationView`.
2. What if one wants to hide both the `DrawerLayout` and the `BottomNavigationView` when viewing authentication views and logging in, and display them when authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement them both and you could hide or show them both programmatically or have an authentication view before your activity that holds your navigation that doesn't `<include/>` these navigation components.

Answer (score 1):

With Jetpack Navigation, you can add a Navigation Host and a Navigation Drawer connected with a main nav graph in the main Activity, and another Navigation Host with a Bottom Navigation connected to a second nav graph inside the default starting fragment.
I found this tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/android-jetpack-navigationui-a7c9f17c510e and its example project https://github.com/sagar-viradiya/NavigationUIDemo

Comment: Please consider including some of the relevant information from your link in the space provided here.